# ChartJS: line graph with labels on the y-axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, chart.js

i am new to chart.js and i need to create a line graph with labels on the y-axis. There are many examples online with labels on the x axis, but what i need is a line graph with the labels on the y-axis and numbers on the x-axis?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should define the values for the vertical axis in the chart configuratoin parameter `data.yLabels`.

Then you define the `yAxis` as a [category cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html).

Further, you need to define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Make sure also that the `data` of your dataset is defined as [individual points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) through objects containing `x` and `y` properties.

> Note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at below runnable code sample.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',  
  data: {
    yLabels: ['Suspended',  'Faulty', 'At-risk', 'Unknown', 'Healthy'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [
        { x: '20:28', y: 'Healthy' },
        { x: '20:47', y: 'Healthy' }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'category',
        ticks: {
          reverse: true,
      },
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'HH:mm',
          unit: 'minute',
          stepSize: 5,
          tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm'
        },
        ticks: {
          min: '20:25',
          max: '20:50',
          padding: 10
      },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```